# NoSuchMethodError for errorHandler when deploying into ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have a servicemix module, which is basicly a camel based route.

It works fine during development and also when deploying in older version of FUSE. However, when deploying in a later version of FUSE, I get

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.company.integration.MyRouteBuilder.errorHandler(Lorg/apache/camel/builder/ErrorHandlerBuilder;)Lorg/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder;

I do not quite get why :-)

The old version used camel 2.6, the new uses Camel 2.9. Both have RouteBuilder.errorHandler as far as i can tell..

br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling (or rather, recreating the instance) helped.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't spend too much time trying to figure that out myself...I'd just start testing with the same version of Camel that I'm going to deploy it under...otherwise even if you get around this issue, others will likely pop up, etc.

If you do have a requirement to run multiple apps that depend on different versions of Camel, then OSGi supports this as long as install the necessary camel bundle versions and setup your applicaiton bundle manifests correctly, etc.

Comment: I see your point, however I've tried upping the camel-version ni my project to that same version used in deploy, but it still fails the same way. I will retry in a fresh smx installation and see if it's any different.